# Using Apache Kafka - pushing data to storage

Tags: apache-kafka

I read about lot of design stories where data reaches storage (both acid and non-sql) through Kafka. Not sure I understand in depth what case it solves. Why not directly?
On other hand, I've never seen other usages of Kafka. Is are other major case of?

Regards,

Comment: Some use case can be found: https://kafka.apache.org/uses

Comment: Just assume we are buffering data using kafka for this use cases in general("data reaches storage (both acid and non-sql) through Kafka"). Why do we need to use buffer in any system holds the  answer for your question in a simple way.

Comment: @Steephen Thank you! If so(just buffering) , I see advantage in 2 cases: A) Kafka is bullet-proof and destination storage is fragile. Why we assume that data's entrance to queue is more safe that data's entrance to destination storage? B) Insensitivity of data has peeks so need to moderate it in time period.  In any case we "earn" new/"artificial" problem that is overflow of input buffer. How we're supposed to handle it? Retry if buffer push fails?

Comment: If you operate Kafka at scale, it isn't bulletproof... The point of using the queue is so that you can democratize access to (often multiple) downstream systems through a consistent API, rather than making a single database/data lake, then pulling it out from there with one-off scripts... Kafka isn't meant for storing files, though, and if you are trying to send files, then you would combine the URI to a file into a Kafka message for consumers to go read from that external storage

Answer (score 2):

In short : coupling. If you write directly to your storage from your source system, you couple the two together. If you want to change one, you directly impact the other. 
Kafka enables you to decouple this, and use data more effectively. Data in Kafka can be used by multiple independent consumers, so if you want to write it to multiple targets you still only extract it from the source system one.

This talk might help you understand further: "**Embrace the Anarchy: Apache Kafka’s Role in Modern Data Architectures**" [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bapHWhtf6fE) / [Slides](https://speakerdeck.com/rmoff/embrace-the-anarchy-apache-kafkas-role-in-modern-data-architectures)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But cases represented in slides are ambiguous even through I intuitively can see in them a sort of salvation. Can we narrow the scope? Let's consider a situation of single data source which should change storage consisting of several DB/non-sql. How I benefit from placing each storage unit change in separate consumer against traditional method of subsequent modification of storage units? Persistence of change?